# C++ linear linked list information. I'm very lost as to what is wrong

Tags: c++, class

EDIT: I figured it out, thanks for the help from those who answered.

Could anybody help me with a bit of my code? I'm new to C++, and I can't get my program to work. It just runs the switch statement without actually executing any of the functions I have written.  I'm sure it's something fairly obvious, but I'd appreciate some help greatly.

My goal is to be able to make a linked list that I can add items to and display them, and ultimately move an item to the end of the list if the user wants to. I really appreciate your reading this. Here is my code:

```
class places  // class to hold all of the places to be inserted into the list
{

public:
    places();  // constructor
    void destroy(); // deconstructor
    void addToList(int placement); //adds items to list
    void displayAll(); // displays all items
    void displayFirst(); // displays first item and moves the first to the end       of the LLL

private:
    places * head;
    places * current;
    places * last;
    places * temp;

    char name[100];
    places * next;
}; 

places::places()
{
head = NULL;
last = NULL;
current = NULL;
temp = NULL;
int placement = 0;
}

void places::destroy()
{
delete[]head;
delete[]last;
delete[]current;
}

void places::addToList(int placement)
{


if (!head)
{
    current = new places;
    cout << "What is the name of the location you'd like to enter?" << endl;
    cin.get (name, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore (200, '\n');
    current -> name;
    current -> next = NULL;
    last -> name; // attachs it to the last node
}
else
{
    head = new places;
    cout << "What is the name of the location you'd like to enter?" << endl;
    cin.get (name, 100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(200, '\n');
    head -> name;
    head -> next = NULL;
    last = head;
}
}
void places::displayAll()
{
if(!head)
{
    cout << "There are no items to display!" << endl;
    return;
}

temp = head;
cout << "Your favorite locations are: " << endl;

while(temp)
{
    cout << temp -> name << endl; // prints the current node
    //below sets the node to be printed to the next one
    if(temp -> next)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "That's all there is!" << endl;
    }
}   
}

void places::displayFirst()
{
if(head)
{
    cout << head -> name << endl;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    temp = head;
    delete[]head -> name;
}
 }

bool again()
{
char answer;

cout << "Do you want to enter another place? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

if(toupper(answer) == 'N')
{
    return false;
}

return true;
}
int main()
{
int i = 0;
places favPlaces;
int option;
do
{
    cout << "These are your options! PICK ONE!!!" << endl;
    cout << "\t1. Add to beginning of list\n";
        cout << "\t2. Add to end of list\n";
        cout << "\t3. Display the list\n";
        cout << "\t4. Display first item\n";
        cout << "\t5. DESTROY THE LIST!\n";


        cout << "Enter a choice : ";
        cin >> option;

    switch(option)
    {

        case 1:
            favPlaces.addToList();
            break;

        case 2: 
            favPlaces.addToList();
            break;

        case 3: 
            favPlaces.displayAll();
            break;

        case 4:
            favPlaces.displayFirst();
            break;

        case 5:
            favPlaces.destroy();
            break;

    }

i++;
}while(i < 4);


}
```

Comment: well, if a switch isnt working as hoped, the first thing to does is add a `default:` field, that print out some debug info ...

Comment: If you allocate something with `new`, you delete it with `delete`, not `delete[]`.

Comment: It seems as thought the issue isn't the switch statement, it's in my function adding to the list.  It doesn't take any info in, it just couts the statement asking for info and then nothing else happens

Answer (score 1):

The main thing I see with the code is failure to distinguish between information *about* the list (the `places` type) and information belonging to each node.

Here's a [short tutorial on linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993882/linked-list-and-reading-from-text-file/14994011#14994011) that I wrote in response to another such beginner's question.

I think that's the best help I can give here, that delving into the current code would not be fruitful. So, take a look at it. Perhaps try to work through the examples. :-)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by distinguishing between the places type and the information belonging to each node? I had a feeling I was missing something in to dealing with individual objects as opposed to the general functions, but I don't fully know what

Comment: @McPluckingtonJr: it doesn't make sense for each node to know about e.g. `head`, `current` and `last`. Conversely, it doesn't make sense for the complete list object to know about `next` (is there another list, to follow this one?). So separate those things. I suggest starting with my tutorial though. For in order to see easily what makes sense or not, some familiarity with the subject matter is needed.