# a linked list with header

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm supposed to write a linked list with header. but I think I have not understood the exact meaning of header! Does header points to the first item of the list or it's the first item itself?! I ask u to check whether my code generates a linked list with header or not?! And if not what should I do in order to have a header linked list? here is the code:

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
    int info;
    node *next; 
    friend class H_list;
};

class node;
class H_list
{
public:
    H_list();
    int isempty();
    void insert();
    void del();
    void display();
private:
    node *header;
    node *L;
};

//*****************************************************************//

H_list::H_list()
{
    header=new node;
    header->next=NULL;
    L=NULL;
}

//*****************************************************************//
```

Comment: I recommend asking your professor what (s)he meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A header (for a singly linked list) is a dummy node at the start that simplifies insertion at the start.

For a circularly linked list the term "header" node is sometimes used about a dummy node that connects the start end end. An empty such list consists just of the header node linking to itself. It eliminates some special cases for insertion and deletion.

In any case the header node needs not be a full, complete node. If the links are at the start of each node, then only that part needs to be there for the header. Also, the header needs not necessarily be dynamically allocated.

Comment: ok where should I define this dummy node?

Comment: I would suggest in the `H_list` constructor. By the way, it can be a good idea to make sure that `H_list` is never copied, by declaring (but not implementing) a `private` copy constructor and ditto copy assignment operator. Or inherit from a class, e.g. called `Non_copyable`, that does that (such a class needs a public default constructor in order to be useful).

Comment: how should I define it in the H_list? node *header=new node; ?

Comment: i once wrote [a small tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993882/linked-list-and-reading-from-text-file/14994011#14994011) in response to a similar SO question.

Answer (score 2):

The header role is to keep track of your list. If you are referring to a singly list the header is located in the beginning of the singly list and it points to the first node.

e.g

```
header->firstNode->secondNode->...
```

The header help locate the first node in your list

*If the list is a double linked list then you need a header and a back to be able to access the list from the beginning or the end easily.*

Comment: useful,I think I got it tnx

Comment: it was my first answer in this wesbite ;) good luck